# Shift reduce conflict

Tags: grammar, conflict, gppg

I'm having a problem understanding the shift/reduce confict for a grammar that I know has no ambiguity. The case is one of the if else type but it's not the 'dangling else' problem since I have mandatory END clauses delimiting code blocks.

Here is the grammar for gppg (Its a Bison like compiler compiler ... and that was not an echo):

```
%output=program.cs

%start program

%token FOR
%token END
%token THINGS
%token WHILE
%token SET
%token IF
%token ELSEIF
%token ELSE
%%

program : statements
        ;

statements : /*empty */
           | statements stmt
           ;

stmt : flow
     | THINGS
     ;

flow : '#' IF '(' ')' statements else
     ;

else : '#' END
     | '#' ELSE statements '#' END
     | elseifs
     ;

elseifs : elseifs '#' ELSEIF statements else
        | '#' ELSEIF statements else
        ;
```

Here is the conflict output:

```
// Parser Conflict Information for grammar file "program.y"

Shift/Reduce conflict on symbol "'#'", parser will shift
 Reduce 10: else -> elseifs
 Shift "'#'":   State-22 -> State-23
  Items for From-state State 22
    10 else: elseifs .
    -lookahead: '#', THINGS, EOF
    11 elseifs: elseifs . '#' ELSEIF statements else 
  Items for Next-state State 23
    11 elseifs: elseifs '#' . ELSEIF statements else 

// End conflict information for parser
```

I already switched arround everything, and I do know how to resolve it, but that solution involves giving up the left recursion on 'elseif' for a right recursion.

Ive been through all the scarse documentation I have found on the internet regarding this issue (I post some links at the end) and still have not found an elegant solution. I know about ANTLR and I don't want to consider it right now. Please limit your solution to Yacc/Bison parsers.

I would appreciate elegant solutions, I managed to do It by eleminating the /* empty */ rules and duplication everything that needed an empty list but in the larger grammar Im working on It just ends up like 'sparghetti grammar syndrome'.

Here are some links:

http://nitsan.org/~maratb/cs164/bison.html

http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/98-01-079

[GPPG, the parser I'm using](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gppg/)

[Bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your revised ELSEIF rule has no markers for a condition -- it should nominally have '(' and ')' added.

More seriously, you now have a rule for

```
elsebody : else
         | elseifs else
         ;
```

and

```
elseifs : /* Nothing */
        | elseifs ...something... 
        ;
```

The 'nothing' is not needed; it is implicitly taken care of by the 'elsebody' without the 'elseifs'.

I would be very inclined to use rules 'opt_elseifs', 'opt_else', and 'end':

```
flow : '#' IF '(' ')' statements opt_elseifs opt_else end
     ;

opt_elseifs : /* Nothing */
            | opt_elseifs '#' ELSIF '(' ')' statements 
            ;

opt_else : /* Nothing */
         | '#' ELSE statements
         ;

end : '#' END
    ;
```

I've not run this through a parser generator, but I find this relatively easy to understand.

Comment: Yes. I too expected it to work, you are right in stating its the easyiest to understand. but I did ran it on the parser and unfortunatly gave 4 shift/reduce conflicts. Run it through gppg and see for yourself. I dont understand (got to get my 'dragon' compilers manual back)

Comment: The answer works if I take out the '#'. Seems the simbol messes up the lookahead token, probably because the parser is LALR(1)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the elseifs clause.

```
elseifs : elseifs '#' ELSEIF statements else
        | '#' ELSEIF statements else
        ;
```

I think the first version is not required, since the else clause refers back to elseifs anyway:

```
else : '#' END
     | '#' ELSE statements '#' END
     | elseifs
     ;
```

What happens if you change elseifs?:

```
elseifs : '#' ELSEIF statements else
        ;
```

Comment: You are right. Eleminationg the line resolved the conflict. I reduced my original grammar to this small one to try and pinpoint the problem and ended up introducing a bug. I think I have to redo my original more complex grammar and work it towards this one to work out the solution.

Comment: Darn: just noticed why it worked. It's right side recursion again. The solution I'm after should do left recursion on the elseifs since they can be a long stream.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Jonathan above seems like it would be the best, but since its not working for you I have a few suggestions you could try that will help you in debugging the error.

Firstly have you considered making the hash/sharp symbol a part of the tokens themselves (i.e. #END, #IF, etc)? So that they get taken out by the lexer, meaning they don't have to be included in the parser.

Secondly I would urge you to rewrite the rules without duplicating any token streams. (Part of the Don't Repeat Yourself principle.) So the rule " '#' ELSEIF statements else " should only exist in one place in that file (not two as you have above).

Lastly I suggest that you look into precedence and associativity of the IF/ELSEIF/ELSE tokens. I know that you should be able to write a parser that doesn't require this but it might be the thing that you need in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still switching thing arround, and my original question had some errors since the **elseifs** sequence had an **else** allways at the end which was wrong. Here is another take at the question, this time I get two shift/reduce conflicts:

```
flow : '#' IF '(' ')' statements elsebody 
     ;

elsebody : else 
         | elseifs else
         ;

else : '#' ELSE statements '#' END
     | '#' END
     ;

elseifs : /* empty */
        | elseifs '#' ELSEIF statements
        ;
```

The conflicts now are:

```
// Parser Conflict Information for grammar file "program.y"

Shift/Reduce conflict on symbol "'#'", parser will shift
 Reduce 12: elseifs -> /* empty */
 Shift "'#'":   State-10 -> State-13
  Items for From-state State 10
    7 flow: '#' IF '(' ')' statements . elsebody 
    4 statements: statements . stmt 
  Items for Next-state State 13
    10 else: '#' . ELSE statements '#' END 
    11 else: '#' . END 
    7 flow: '#' . IF '(' ')' statements elsebody 

Shift/Reduce conflict on symbol "'#'", parser will shift
 Reduce 13: elseifs -> elseifs, '#', ELSEIF, statements
 Shift "'#'":   State-24 -> State-6
  Items for From-state State 24
    13 elseifs: elseifs '#' ELSEIF statements .
    -lookahead: '#'
    4 statements: statements . stmt 
  Items for Next-state State 6
    7 flow: '#' . IF '(' ')' statements elsebody 

// End conflict information for parser
```

Empty rules just aggravate the gppg i'm affraid. But they seem so natural to use I keep trying them.

I already know right recursion solves the problem as *1800 INFORMATION* has said. But I'm looking for a solution with **left recursion** on the **elseifs clause**.

Answer (score 0):

```
elsebody : elseifs else
         | elseifs
         ;

elseifs : /* empty */
        | elseifs '#' ELSEIF statements
        ;

else : '#' ELSE statements '#' END
     ;
```

I think this should left recurse and always terminate.

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunatly ... 5 shift/reduce conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

OK - here is a grammar (not minimal) for if blocks.   I dug it out of some code I have (called adhoc, based on hoc from Kernighan & Plauger's "The UNIX Programming Environment").  This outline grammar compiles with Yacc with no conflicts.

```
%token  NUMBER IF ELSE
%token  ELIF END
%token  THEN
%start program

%%

program
    :   stmtlist
    ;

stmtlist
    :   /* Nothing */
    |   stmtlist stmt
    ;

stmt
    :   ifstmt
    ;

ifstmt
    :   ifcond endif
    |   ifcond else begin
    |   ifcond eliflist begin
    ;

ifcond
    :   ifstart cond then stmtlist
    ;

ifstart
    :   IF
    ;

cond
    :   '(' expr ')'
    ;

then
    :   /* Nothing */
    |   THEN
    ;

endif
    :   END IF begin
    ;

else
    :   ELSE stmtlist END IF
    ;

eliflist
    :   elifblock
    |   elifcond eliflist begin         /* RIGHT RECURSION */
    ;

elifblock
    :   elifcond else begin
    |   elifcond endif
    ;

elifcond
    :   elif cond then stmtlist end
    ;

elif
    :   ELIF
    ;

begin
    :   /* Nothing */
    ;

end
    :   /* Nothing */
    ;

expr
    :   NUMBER
    ;

%%
```

I used 'NUMBER' as the dummy element, instead of THINGS, and I used ELIF instead of ELSEIF.  It includes a THEN, but that is optional.  The 'begin' and 'end' operations were used to grab the program counter in the generated program - and therefore should be removable from this without affecting it.

There was a reason I thought I needed to use right recursion instead of the normal left recursion - but I think it was to do with the code generation strategy I was using, rather than anything else.  The question mark in the comment was in the original; I remember not being happy with it.  The program as a whole does work - it is a project that's been on the back burner for the last decade or so (hmmm...I did some work at the end of 2004 and beginning of 2005; prior to that, it was 1992 and 1993).

I've not spent the time working out why this compiles conflict-free and what I outlined earlier does not.  I hope it helps.