# Is there a shift/reduce error in this yacc code?

Tags: grammar, yacc

I'm getting a message from yacc saying that there is a shift/reduce conflict.  I think it's coming from this part of the yacc file.

```
statement : expression_stmt
          | compound_stmt
          | selection_stmt
          | iteration_stmt
          | return_stmt ;

selection_stmt : IF '(' expression ')' statement
               | IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement ;

expression : var '=' expression | simple_expression ;
```

Can you see a conflict?  How can it be fixed?

Comment: No, I don't see a conflict, but your second question seems to imply that you do. Anyway, this can't be your full grammar (you're missing the rules for `expression_stmt`, `compound_stmt`, etc.). If you're having an actual conflict with your grammar, please post all the relevant bits so that we can try and reproduce it.

Comment: @arthur: the full grammar is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752185/whats-wrong-with-my-grammar

Comment: @Adrien: OK, thanks :-)  So it seems it's a duplicate.

Comment: @arthur: no it's just that our OP is not able to do his homework himself. each error pointed in an answer gives way to a new question where he wants us to correct his mistakes... using this iterative approach, he might be able to answer his assignment in some weeks, and even manage to get a pretty decent mark without doing anything...

Comment: No, I am learning dialectically.  Dialectical learning is one of the best ways to learn.

Comment: @Adrien: Or he will paste the answers in the wrong order, to his teacher's puzzlement!

Comment: @phenom: asking "what is the problem ?" and pasting a lot of code is not learning dialectically. we would like you to think by yourself and perform a bit of research. can you show us that you made some research ? did you ask google what a shift/reduce conflict is ? what did you learn from your search ?

Comment: What does “learning dialectically” mean anyway?  But what the heck, I'm teaching dialectically.  I answer “I don't see a conflict” as a comment and “I'm seeing a conflict” as an answer.

Comment: There was actually a lot of code, and I narrowed it down to where I thought the problem was.  I learned from what someone else said that a shift/reduce conflict happens with ambiguous grammar and this is an instance of the famous "dangling else" problem.  I learned that all from other peoplee not from google.  That's dialectical learning!

Comment: @Adrien: Actually, I think his grammar is seriously screwed up.  There's no way any language would have ambiguities such as the one I outlined in my answer.

Comment: @arthur: you think so ? then what about C ? iirc, early versions of pascal also had the same problem.

Comment: @Adrien: Right, I never thought about that.  Then again, I never had to write a C parser :-)

Comment: @arthur: i always found C was clunky... now that we laughed a bit and you took the time to find a perfectly valid answer (thanks for the effort), can we close it as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196179/shift-reduce-conflict ?

Comment: @Adrien: In retrospect I'm not a little proud of myself.  I never took any classes in CS, it only took me one hour to understand a common problem in compiler techniques :-)  But I can't vote to close, I have only 927 rep as of time of writing.  You need 3k apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm seeing a conflict.  The `selection_statement` rule matches expressions like

```
IF(<expression 1>)
THEN
    IF(<expression 2>)
    THEN <expression statement 1>
    ELSE <expression statement 2>
```

But that's ambiguous.  It could also be

```
IF(<expression 1>)
THEN
    IF(<expression 2>)
    THEN <expression statement 1>
ELSE <expression statement 2>
```

Comment: Hey, I had to discover it by hand!  I inspected the grammar for that.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was in there.  Just needed to confirm.  So how can it be fixed?

Comment: @Phenom: you have asked this precise question in a number of different ways over the last few days.  Just *read* the answers!  Your solution is there.